# Update part of string which contains int numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking on how to update a part of string.
String looks like this: `'0 0 0 6 7 2 6 8 6 1 7 5 3 2 4 9 9 4'`

What I want is to change first `9` numbers of string to `0`.
Any suggestions on how to do in only with MySQL?

Comment: Which version of SQL?

Comment: Version of SQL: 5.5.41

Comment: Please add MySQL to your Question tags :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty if your string format/length is fixed:

```
-- Concat with hardcode prefix with tail of the string:
SELECT CONCAT("0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ", SUBSTRING("0 0 0 6 7 2 6 8 6 1 7 5 3 2 4 9 9 4", 19))

-- Update
UPDATE {TABLE}
SET {COLUMN} = CONCAT("0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ", SUBSTRING({COLUMN}, 19))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it is tested):

```
select 
CONCAT(
LEFT('0 0 0 6 7 2 6 8 6 1 7 5 3 2 4 9 9 4', INSTR('0 0 0 6 7 2 6 8 6 1 7 5 3 2 4 9 9 4','9')-1)             
,'0',
RIGHT( '0 0 0 6 7 2 6 8 6 1 7 5 3 2 4 9 9 4',CHAR_LENGTH('0 0 0 6 7 2 6 8 6 1 7 5 3 2 4 9 9 4')-1- CHAR_LENGTH(LEFT('0 0 0 6 7 2 6 8 6 1 7 5 3 2 4 9 9 4', INSTR('0 0 0 6 7 2 6 8 6 1 7 5 3 2 4 9 9 4','9')-1)))
)
```

Assume that `s='0 0 0 6 7 2 6 8 6 1 7 5 3 2 4 9 9 4'` (and can be every strings)

```
select 
CONCAT(
LEFT(s, INSTR(s,'9')-1)             
,'0',
RIGHT(s,CHAR_LENGTH(s)-1- CHAR_LENGTH(LEFT(s, INSTR(s,'9')-1)))
)
```

see Demo: http://rextester.com/OIMXCY58613